# Rigged Blender model doesn't preserve volume when exported as FBX

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, .fbx

The cylinder of the revolver shrinks in scale after it's exported to FBX. Although I toggled "Preserve Volume", it appears that Blender FBX's exporter applies it once to the revolver mesh, but ignores it for the cylinder mesh.

Here's how the animation is supposed to look:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/607260974088454154/627367561499115559/swagfire.mp40001-0035.mp4
Here's how the animation looks when reimported:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/605246613379612675/627394105609027594/test.mp4
Models are posted in here: osted from here: https://developer.blender.org/T70340

The developer said that it was a rigging issue, but he didn't give me the specifics about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a weighting issue: the cylinder is weighted to the cylinder bone AND to the grip bone, while it should be weighted to the cylinder bone only (the same applyes to the trigger and the Thingy).

You can remove thoose unwanted weights, but as the animation has been done with them, it will have to be redone or twicked.

The difference between the blend file and the FBX probably has to do with the normalization between weights that Blender does as default, while the FBX format breaks.

[image]

Comment: You're my hero! You, along with other guests, are free to download and use my model. Even for commercial reasons. Tell me if this includes the textures.

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sms-357-a756c1cefb544d48a9f1250e542cd4a5